# JQuery image selector

Tags: jquery

When any image in parent 'div' is clicked background of that parent should change. When I use variable name instead of "img" it is working, but I don't want to write separately write the same code for every image. Is there something wrong in selecting all images via $("img") ?

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css({'background-color': 'black'});
})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what variable name? add html sample too.

Comment: all elements are created in javaScript and stored in variables

Comment: Only major problem I can see with this is that it would affect any image on your page, not just the ones in your container.  If you change the selector to '#myContainer img' it would apply to every img element within the element with an id of #myContainer.

Comment: it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/lvil/0hsmcLth/

Comment: If they're all created in JS, you'll also do better to delegate teh event handler using $('#myContainer').on('click', 'img', function() ...) as that will handle the dynamically added imgs

Comment: Finding every image via .find() did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding every image in parent element is better

```
$('body').find('img').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css({'background-color': 'black'});
})
```